# Abusing discount code by entering fake information

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, promotions

We have the promotion rule "Uses per Customer =1". Today, we noticed one customer (based on payment information) uses the discount code several times, since he is entering fake info. Is there any way to prevent such scenario.

Comment: is he entering different email id or using same email id ?

Comment: In some purchases, he's entered same email. In others, he's entered different emails. We caught him based on his pay pal payment info.

Comment: if he entered different email address, than its not his problem, magento will work like that only. `based on  customer = based on email address ` . if he uses same email address than also he got discount means there is some problem with magento. please check with that.

Comment: Okey the record is this way, two order with same email address which one has used the discount, so fine then.  Other his purchases with fake info in billing form but with  identical payment info which has used the discount in all!

Comment: if he use different email address and getting discount means, thats how system will work. for my knowledge we cann ot do anything. or may be you can try with restricting discount on i.p address basis.

Comment: Wish to have email validation on magento like what sending email does...Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, he is entering different email id and getting benefit of coupon codes.

if he entered different email address, than its not his problem, magento will work like that only. `based on customer = based on email address`

may be you can try with restricting discount on i.p address.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to set such condition, each ip can use once?

Comment: @Zinat sorry , i have no idea. bettter you can post new question.